# Send email with html tags using mailgun

Tags: c#, email, mailgun

I have this code for sending email using mailgun:

```
public async Task SendMail(string replyTo, string to, string cc, string subject, string message)
    {
        var smtpServer = config[ConfigurationSMTP_Server];
        var smtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(config[Configuration_SMTP_Port]);
        var smtpUsername = config[Configuration.SMTP_Username];
        var smtpPassword = config[Configuration.SMTP_Password];

        MimeMessage mail = new MimeMessage();

        mail.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(String.Empty, smtpUsername));
        
        mail.ReplyTo.Add(new MailboxAddress(String.Empty, replyTo));
   
        mail.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(String.Empty, to));
        
        mail.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress(String.Empty, cc));
       

        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = message,
        };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect(smtpServer, smtpPort, false);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

            client.Authenticate(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);

            await client.SendAsync(mail);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }

    }
```

It works but the br, p html tags doesn't seem to apply to the mail. How can I refractor this to do so?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mailgun, but are you sure TextPart is correct? Should you be using an HTML property to make the message html content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick

```
mail.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
{
            Text = message,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recipient-variables and v: functionality provided by Mailgun.

For example following is a JSON string -

```
r = '{
"foo@boo.com": {"FirstName": "Toby","LastName": "Moon"},
"yoo@too.com": {"FirstName": "Bobby","LastName": "Sun"}
}'
```

Assign it to recipient-variables while calling the API.

```
res = requests.post(
        "API url",
        auth=("api", "API key"),   
        data={  
                "from": "<yourdomain@yourdomain.com">,  
                "to": ["List of Emails"],
                "subject": "Test Email",
                "recipient-variables": r,
                'v:FirstName':'%recipient.FirstName%',
                'v:LastName':'%recipient.LastName%',
        })
    print(res)
```

You can then use %recipient.value% anywhere to reference it dynamically.

The following link has steps included -  [Mailgun Recipient Variables](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html?highlight=batch#batch-sending)

The above is an example in Python.